# Files Shown in Terminal not Show on Desktop

Tags: command-line, files, filemanager, aircrack-ng, find

I have an issue where I am creating *.cap* files with *aircrack-ng* and am saving them to the desktop, but I can't see them. When I use the `ls` command in the terminal they show up, but just not on the graphical desktop view. I want to be able to see them on the desktop and not just through the terminal. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** Turns out I am not saving them to the desktop, but rather the `/home/user/` directory. The hidden files show up when I press <kbd>CTR</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, but they don't show up in the terminal; the only file showing up in the terminal when I use the `ls` command is the desktop *(sorry for the topic edit)*. How can I get the hidden files to show up in the terminal as well?

Comment: What is your file manager?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al ~/Desktop`? (Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/496787/edit) it into your question)

Comment: please post your ls list screen shot and your file manager

Comment: I wish there was a way to accept two answers because I asked two questions :/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files that start with a `.` are hidden from the graphical interface.

To view them, just open up your file browser and go to 'Edit'->'Preferences' and check 'Show hidden files and backup files'.

You can also toggle the hidden files using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

**EDIT:**

To get the hidden files to show up in terminal, use:

```
cd
ls -al
```

`cd` takes you back to your home folder while `ls -al` lists (the -l flag) all files (the -a flag) hidden or not.

Comment: Thank you for this information! It solved one of my two issues, my new one now edited to the same post. I would give this answer a plus if I could, but I don't have 15 reputation yet haha.

Answer (score 1):

To view files list use `ls` command. 
To view hidden files as well use `ls -a` or `la` commands.

Hidden files will have `.` before them.

Eg: you should use `ls /home/user/` and for hidden files `la /home/user/` for list view `ls -al /home/user/`

Comment: Although `la` doesn't work, `ls -a` does. This may be because this is an Ubuntu focused site and I'm using Kali Linux, but I don't know for sure. Thank you very much! This completes the second part of the answer to my questions :).

Comment: `ls ~` is the same as `ls /home/USER` by the way

Comment: yes its the same.